# Loop through each tabs in excel and active it one by one in Excel by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to come up with a solution in VBA, what I want to do is to active each tab in this file and active certain cell for each tab based on different requirement. However my code didn't work, for the statement:

```
wkbk1.ws.Activate
```

It said Object doesn't not support this property or method(not sure why, my ws is the worksheet right?)

My code is:

```
For Each ws In wkbk1.Worksheets
wkbk1.ws.Activate ' error here
If wkbk1.ws.Name = "Page" Then
wkbk1.ws.Range("B2").Select
ElseIf wkbk1.ws.Name = "Contents" Or "Results" Then
wkbk1.ws.Range("B1").Select
ElseIf wkbk1.ws.Name = "Logic" Then
wkbk1.ws.Range("C1").Select
Else
wkbk1.ws.Range("A1").Select
End If
Next
```

Can anyone please give me an idea for why I am having this issue?

Comment: Directly after your `For Each ws In ...` you must use the `ws` directly (within this loop without a leading workbook-reference) to reference each sheet, like `ws.Name` or `ws.Range()`. You should also [avoid selecting or activating anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/10908769).

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of "activate each tab one by one" is? Because that doesn't make any sens at all and you will only see the last activation in the end.

Comment: In addition to the comments above, what's the purpose of selecting the cells? What do you want to do with them? Since you know how to refer to them, you can do anything you want without selecting them. Currently you are not doing anything. Also, have you `set` your `wkbk1` object?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for you response, the purpose is I have several tabs in the file, I want to when people open the file, the mouse is not click everywhere, for example, some in A10, some in B30, it is not necessary to be A1, but the 
arrow shouldn't not be randomly everywhere

Comment: @StavrosJon thanks for you response, the purpose is I have several tabs in the file, I want to when people open the file, the mouse is not click everywhere, for example, some in A10, some in B30, it is not necessary to be A1, but the arrow shouldn't not be randomly everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Activate (You don't need it)

Instead of using such a line

```
wkbk1.ws.Range("B2").Select
```

use Application.GoTo like this

```
Application.Goto ws.Range("B2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `Select Case` to determine the address to jump to for every sheet. And finally use the [Application.Goto method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.goto) to jump there.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InitializeWorksheetsSelectedCells()
    Dim JumpToAddress As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Page"
                JumpToAddress = "B2"
            Case "Contents", "Results"
                JumpToAddress = "B1"
            Case "Logic"
                JumpToAddress = "C1"
            Case Else
                JumpToAddress = "A1"
        End Select

        Application.Goto ws.Range(JumpToAddress)
    Next ws
End Sub
```